# Why is the GIC interrupt controller address not fixed

Tags: linux, arm, interrupt

When using ARM interrupt, GIC operation requires reading GIC base address from CP15 before controlling, as follows:

```
mrc p15, 4, r1, c15, c0, 0 //1.Read GIC base address into r1
add r1, r1, #0X2000        //2.GIC interface end base address   
ldr r0, [r1, #0XC]         //3.Read interrupt number
```

When performing the third step, the operation is a memory address, that is, the GIC address is in the memory address. Why does the GIC base address need to be read from CP15 instead of a fixed memory address, the GIC base address is still Will it change?

Comment: it is likely compiled into the core by the chip vendor as I think the GIC Is an add on, extra cost item.  For the core in question this can be looked up there is at least one compiled in peripheral address.   There are items like this that are chip specific and can as a result vary widely.

Comment: will it change runtime?  is that your question?  you have to read both the arm documentation and the chip documentation.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I printed the base address of gic, it is 0x00A00000, and then read the Reference Manual, and found that the description of this address in the memory map is like this: 00A0_0000 00A0_7FFF 32 KB "ARM Peripherals: GIC400 Only visible to ARM core (s )",I have learned. Thank you very much, have a nice day.

Comment: In this case, should it be possible to use the address 0x00A00000 without reading the gic address from CP15?

Comment: again addresses like these can be or are the responsibility of the chip vendor, meaning not arm.  arm will have signals on the edge of the design for these kinds of things and the chip vendor hooks those up, that can be hard wired or dynamic based on the chip design.  Now if the documentation shows that it is a fixed address and when you read it  it matches the documentation then FOR THAT CHIP it is probably safe to just assume that is that address all the time.  But should still read more and confirm or just fetch the address each time you do something.

Comment: it might be called PERIPHBASE in the arm documentation.  if not then something similar.  unfortunately we dont have direct access to the code but the TRM will still include some of the signal names.

Comment: honestly on the chips I am involved in we know the address and just use it without talking to the coprocessor.

Comment: thank you for your answer, and i have got it, your reply has been very helpful to me, thank you very much